# SQL - How to get transaction count month to date

Tags: sql, group-by

I am trying to get transaction count month to date. For now I am providing date between `from_date` and `to_date`.

How can I get results for a particular month in month to date ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [Ask]. Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Tag appropriate database name with you so far created script.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what SQL your using, but if its SQL Server then it has a built in function `DatePart` [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) I'd expect most of the major SQL dialects to have something similar.

So your `where` clause would be something like `where datepart(mm, to_date) = 4` (for April)

If your version SQL doesn't have the date functions, then you can fallback to the cruder string manipulation.  Assuming your date is yyyymmdd, then you could use a sub string function to pull out the mm part, convert that to a integer and perform your comparison.